# Headset App that diplays checking account balance of People as a Tooltip above heads

Tags: mobile, computer-vision

The Apple Vision Pro Headset came out earlier this year (2024) .

Is there already a Vision OS App (or any other Headset OS App) that  displays the current Checking Account balance of random people above their heads? Displaying net worth/debt would also be an interesting alternative.
The app should display this information like a tooltip, or like a "health level", one of those green/red bars known from character figures in computer games.
The app should do this in public space, wherever there is internet, e.g., in a shopping mall, with any person, in real time.

What I am describing here is from a science-fiction book, "Freedom" by Daniel Suarez. In that book, some protagonists wear high-tech glasses stocked with such an app.
This kind of app was out-of-reach, impossible to implement, back in  2010, around the time when the book was released. But now an app like this *is* quite feasible.

So I am asking here to determine a point in time when science fiction became reality.  And I know that there are massive problems with data protection such an app would imply.

However, probably static software (installed on a PC or a server) can already do a real-time lookup like this, albeit for less confidential information, e.g. for  security cameras or for license plate readers.

Comment: Getting bank account information from random people on the street without their consent would be 1) a HUGE legal issue, any bank that gave out that information would be violating bank secrecy. 2) a not as huge but still big technical issue, as a person could have multiple checking accounts, banks (and credit unions I guess) would need a common interface to query that information, etc which the common SWIFT API would never expose for (1) legal motives.

Answer (score 2):

There was an excellent short story, many years ago, in [Asimov's Science Fiction magazine](https://www.asimovs.com/), where only the police had such glasses, and everyone in a crowd had a green tick, yellow question mark or red exclamation point floating above their heads.

That is likely to come true fairly soon, I would imagine. At least in some coutries. It is currently already technically possible.

However, I am going to answer your question "no, there is no such app. Nor is there likely to ever be such an app available to the general public on privacy grounds. Do you think that you could pass a law mandating that everyone wear a T-shirt with their salary/net worth/income?".

Currently, no!!! Future? Ask https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/  This is more of a social problem than technical.

Now, if only I could find that old Asimov's mag. That was a great story, and I would like to reread it.